# How to have 2 or more DropDownlist in 1 row in Gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a List Product. The product list is just like in the picture.

If I display directly from the list to the Gridview.

It will be like in the picture: The rows will hv other Product rows if product type varies.

Here's [a link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9LFWc9viWmUM1JyWWZhdmV6RzQ)!.

How can I achieve this? I tried looking up on Rowspan, but unsure how I can retrieve back the Dropdownlist record. 
Here's [a link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9LFWc9viWmUX2VYTVowMzNyaXM)!.

I tried searching but none found so far. The nearest I found was just labels.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [link](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/How-to-populate-DropDownList-in-GridView-in-ASPNet.aspx)
 for the implementation.

Hope it helps!!

I am not sure if you are trying to access the dropdown value on button click. If this is the scenario try using the below code.

```
var tmpValue = ((DropDownList)gvRowItem.Cells[/*cellId*/].FindControl("/*dropDownListId*/")).SelectedValue;
```

If you need to populate the value on selection of dropdown within the grid, you can add the postback event and handle the same as below

```
Control ctrl = gridview.Rows[/*rowId*/].FindControl("/*dropDownListId*/") as DropDownList;
DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)ctrl;
var selectedValue = ddl.SelectedValue;
```

Let me know in case you are expecting something else

Comment: Don't just paste a link in here. They can expire! Please summerize the basic idea of the site you're refering to.

Comment: I look at that. I can get it bind to the gridview, but couldn't achieve the 2nd links at my post.